# Is it possible to update a forked project from its head in android studio

Tags: android-studio, github

"Head" in this question refers to the project that I forked from.

For instance:  I have forked a project on Github.  I cloned my fork of the original project from Android Studio, and I do all my development work from there, initiating branches for each change.  Occasionally the master fork is updated with new code changes in the head project.  Currently to update my fork with these changes I must go to Github website, and create a pull request to get the changes into my fork.  I must then create pull requests to each development branch in my fork from the master branch, if I want that branch to get the new code.

I am looking for a way to do the pull request from the "HEAD" project from Android Studio.

Is this possible?